# How do I display taxonomy info from a wp-query?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a wp-query that works a treat on a small section of my website's dashboard - it displays a list of repeat jobs (CPTs) that are due in 6 weeks time - I'm having issues with displaying a taxonomy related to the post.

So far I've got

```
<?php 

// get posts
$before_date = date("Ymd", strtotime("+6 weeks"));

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'pre_jobs',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'pre_job_due_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
     'key' => 'pre_job_due_date',
     'value' => $before_date, 
     'compare' => '<', 
     ),
   ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pre_job_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'repeat' )
        ),
    ),
));

if( $posts ): ?>

    <hr>
    <div class="dashpanel">
    <div class="duedate-head">Due Date</div>
    <div class="jobnumber-head">Job Type</div>
    <div class="client-head">Client/Requestor</div>
    <div class="customer-head">Customer</div>
</div>
<hr>


    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

        setup_postdata( $post )

        ?>
        <?php $job_type = get_field('pre_job_job_type', $client->ID ); ?>
        <?php $customer = get_field('pre_job_customer', $client->ID ); ?>
        <?php $job_client = get_field('pre_job_requestor', $client->ID ); ?>

        <div class="dashpanel">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="duedate"><?php the_field('pre_job_due_date'); ?></div>
    <div class="jobnumber"><?php echo $job_type[0]->post_title; ?></div>
    <div class="client"><?php echo $job_client[0]->post_title; ?></div>
    <div class="customer"><?php echo $customer[0]->post_title; ?></div></a>
    </div>
    <hr>


    <?php endforeach; ?>



    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p>No upcoming jobs to book in.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not sure where I need to put the

```
<?php 
$pre_job_type = get_field('pre_job_job_type');
if( $term ): ?>
```

Code - every time I add this code it breaks. Or am I going completely wrong somewhere?

Comment: Might sound simple, but are you adding `global $post;` before this code?

Comment: Hi John, no. At the end of the wp-query I've got `if( $posts ): ?>` and that's it. Where would I add this & what's the significance of it?

Comment: There are various WordPress functions you can choose from for retrieving/displaying taxonomy and term details. For examples, [`the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/) and [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/). But what are the `$term` in your code?

Comment: Hi Sally, I've edited my question with the full code

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't really get what that `$term` is and is for? I mean, in your attempts, where/how did you define the variable? What is it supposed to contain and do? And is that `pre_job_job_type` field a ACF Post Object field? Also, what's the slug of the taxonomy you're trying to query its info? Are you actually trying to get the terms assigned to the `pre_job_job_type` post?

Comment: Adding to @SallyCJ's questions, I'm also not following what's being requested here. What do you mean by "displaying a taxonomy"? Display a link to a taxonomy archive? Show the name? Maybe if you a) confirmed you're using ACF, b) explained exactly what the field types you're using, and c) explained or imaged the desired output, we'd have a better chance of providing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code after you open the `if ($posts)` loop: 
It will show the taxonomy to which this publication is related. with a link to it.
If you prefer, you can remove the link and display only the title of the term with the call `$term->name`

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_HERE' );
if ( $terms != null ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_HERE' );
        echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url( site_url() ) . '/your-taxonomy-here/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . ' ' . $term->term_id . ' ' . $term->count . '</a></li>';
        unset( $term );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer. Describe what your code is doing and why it can solve the problem. Also add some information where to use this code. Thank you and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your expected taxonomy? If haven't at first create the taxonomy on your functions.php file or where you have created your custom post type.

Example:

```
/**
 * Register a private 'Genre' taxonomy for post type 'book'.
 *
 * @see register_post_type() for registering post types.
 */
function wpdocs_register_taxonomy() {
    $args = array(
        'label'        => __( 'Job Type', 'textdomain' ),
        'public'       => true,
        'rewrite'      => true,
        'hierarchical' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'pre_job_job_type', 'pre_jobs', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_register_taxonomy', 0 );
```

**Or OOP approach:**

```
public function wpdocs_register_taxonomy() {
        $args = array(
            'label'        => __( 'Job Type', 'textdomain' ),
            'public'       => true,
            'rewrite'      => true,
            'hierarchical' => true
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'pre_job_job_type', 'pre_jobs', $args );
    }

/**
* When class is instantiated
*/

public function __construct() {

    add_action('init', array($this, 'wpdocs_register_taxonomy'));// Register texonomy

}
```

Now your taxonomies are **ready to display**. Place this code where ever you want to display the taxonomies.

```
$pre_job_types = get_categories('taxonomy=pre_job_job_type&post_type=pre_jobs'); 
foreach ($pre_job_types as $job_type ) : ?>  
     <span> <?php echo $job_type->name; </span>
endforeach;
```

If you want to query your custom post with the taxonomy, follow this:

```
               $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'pre_jobs',
                    'status' => 'published',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'pre_job_job_type',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => array( 'repeat' )
                      ) 
                    ) 
                  );
                  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then continue as a normal query. This query only display the posts whose taxonomy is "repeat".